# Could createXHR+open+send only part of the text?

Tags: javascript, ajax, responsetext

I have a file with some content in it and I would like to use req to send part of the file once a time, for example, each time 500 lines of the content.

========================current code====================================

```
               var req = createXHR();
               var url = "http://" + report.host + "/real/" + this.fdir + "/" + this.fname + window.location.search;
               req.open("GET", url, false);
               req.send();
```

Question is:

1. What can I do to make req only send x to y lines of data, rather than send whole file?
2. What will happen if I do nothing in the case an extremly large file?

Comment: so, the code in the question is irrelevant, as you'd need to perform this on the server side - please tell us a bit about what languages are available to you on your server side

Comment: Thanks. This is server side code and I am using javascript. On user side, I open a sub window to display the content I read from a file, and I want server to send 0~500 lines of data at the first time. Then on the browser, if I scroll down to the end, it will request and server will send another 501~1000 lines of the data of that file.